# finding total file size of all files in a directory

Tags: python

So currently I'm using the code seen below to calculate the size of all the files in a directory. this works fine for my uses. just wondered if there was a way to make it get the total file size of specific file types such as .py files or .txt.

```
total_file = sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f))
```

Comment: you can alwyays include more conditions in your generator for sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.endswith('.py')`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/endswith.html) (for filtering for .py files):

```
total_file = sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir('.')
    if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.py'))
```