# Finding total file size in directory in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm attempting to walk through each directory and write the result to a dataframe. I would also like to sum the files in each directory and write that to a frame. Here is my code so far. I've seen this question but I don't know how to convert this answer to a format that is usable within my code ([finding total file size of all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968213/finding-total-file-size-of-all-files-in-a-directory)).

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import time

# sets the display so that when the code prints, it is readable
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 3000)

# Initialize the dataframe
col_names = ['directory', 'file name', 'file size', 'file date', 'total in directory']
files = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('G:\OM\Permits'):
    print(dirpath)
    files.loc[dirpath, 'directory'] = dirpath
    print("")
    with os.scandir(dirpath) as i:
     for entry in i:
         if entry.is_file():
             print(entry.name)
             files.loc[entry.name, 'file name'] = entry.name
             file_size = round((os.path.getsize(entry) / 1048576),4)
             files.loc[file_size, 'file size'] = file_size
             files_date = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(entry)))
             files.loc[files_date, 'file date'] = files_date
             total = 0
             for file_size in files:
                  total += float(file_size)
                  files.loc[total, 'total in directory'] = total


df = pd.DataFrame(files)
print(df)
#df.to_csv('G Drive List of Files.csv')
```

When getting to the total portion of the field I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tkravits/PycharmProjects/Folder/Pandas_FolderSearch.py", line 29, in <module>
    total += float(file_size)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'directory'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ending up being my solution. There's a formatting issue with the dataframe that I will need to solve/address in a new question.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import time

# sets the display so that when the code prints, it is readable
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 3000)

# Initialize the dataframe
col_names = ['directory', 'file name', 'file size', 'file date', 'total in directory']
files = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('G:\OM\Permits'):
    print(dirpath)
    files.loc[dirpath, 'directory'] = dirpath
    #print("")
    with os.scandir(dirpath) as i:
     for entry in i:
         if entry.is_file():
             print(entry.name)
             files.loc[entry.name, 'file name'] = entry.name
             file_size = round((os.path.getsize(entry) / 1048576),4)
             files.loc[file_size, 'file size'] = file_size
             files_date = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(entry)))
             files.loc[files_date, 'file date'] = files_date
     for file_size in dirpath:
         total_file = sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.scandir(dirpath) if os.path.isfile(f))
         files.loc[total_file, 'total in directory'] = total_file


df = pd.DataFrame(files)
print(df)
#df.to_csv('G Drive List of Files.csv')
```